# How to call Controller function to a service/factory?

Tags: angularjs

```
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){

    $scope.test = function(callback){
        callback("return Message");
    }  

 });

 .service('MyService',function(){
          // use MyCtrl
  });
```

How can i call MyCtrl inside my service and use the test function?

Comment: check this - [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28884380/5198430) . It might help you

Comment: isn't the proper way is the other way around? You'd normally like to inject your service to your controller and use functionality.. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Can you explain more why you want to do this?

Comment: check answer if you have any confusion free to ask me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call controller function from service in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884028/call-controller-function-from-service-in-angularjs)